# Android Looper handler handleMessage is not called after sending a message to it (HTC EVO 3D)

Tags: handler, looper

I am experiencing a very strange problem:
On HTC EVO 3D, sometimes, a looper does not call handleMessage after a message is sent to the looper's handler. It happens twice and very difficult to reproduce. The first time I caught it is after eight hours stress test. There was no errors and exceptions. However, I did not print out whether the message is successfully sent to the looper, but I am sure the looper thread is still alive and running through debugger.

I used the exactly same mechanism for more than half year and never had any problems. I am wondering does anyone meet the same problem? Is it the device issue?

Thanks,

Simon